# Revert cherry-pick --abort?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I had cherry-picked over 70 commits over the past week from my master branch to another branch with commands:

```
git cherry-pick -x -n <commit-id>
(made some modifications and then)
git commit
```

Status says *Your branch is ahead of 'origin/another-branch' by 76 commits.*

Just a moment ago I thought I could continue my task and pick some commits. The very first commit for today was a wrong one and wanted to undo this cherry-picking, and used the command:

```
git cherry-pick --abort
```

And boom, all the 70+ commits seem to be gone. Status says *Your branch is ahead of 'origin/another-branch' by 2 commits.*

Reflog show these last 2 lines:

```
c398477f HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to c398477fa2b2e0e78cb628c75df81b2c1ec411cd
8369312d HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to another-branch
```

Please say there's **somehow possible to revert the abort?** These commits are/was only in my local branch. And, **how the hell did it wipe all the cherry-picked commits, even after I explicityly commited each one of them?**

This is the reflog just when I started my cherry-picking a week ago:

```
d8a71aca HEAD@{52}: checkout: moving from another-branch to dev
8369312d HEAD@{53}: commit: xxx
...
3bb1ff07 HEAD@{127}: commit: xxx
2b9b6542 HEAD@{128}: commit: xxx
c398477f HEAD@{129}: reset: moving to HEAD^
b373db60 HEAD@{130}: commit: xxx
c398477f HEAD@{131}: commit: xxx
8fb419aa HEAD@{132}: commit: xxx
844cbe24 HEAD@{133}: reset: moving to 844cbe2499aadcd0d014999ddb6f847c1d940440
844cbe24 HEAD@{134}: reset: moving to 844cbe24
41e7dbed HEAD@{135}: checkout: moving from 844cbe2499aadcd0d014999ddb6f847c1d940440 to aller-dev
844cbe24 HEAD@{136}: checkout: moving from another-branch to 844cbe24
41e7dbed HEAD@{137}: reset: moving to HEAD^
844cbe24 HEAD@{138}: reset: moving to HEAD^
81bf86ac HEAD@{139}: cherry-pick: xxx
844cbe24 HEAD@{140}: checkout: moving from dev to another-branch
```

And same with `reflog --all`:

```
c398477f refs/heads/another-branch@{0}: reset: moving to c398477fa2b2e0e78cb628c75df81b2c1ec411cd
8369312d refs/heads/another-branch@{1}: commit: xxx
6a4da110 refs/heads/another-branch@{2}: commit: xxx
...
2b9b6542 refs/heads/another-branch@{75}: commit: xxx
c398477f refs/heads/another-branch@{76}: reset: moving to HEAD^
b373db60 refs/heads/another-branch@{77}: commit: xxx
c398477f refs/heads/another-branch@{78}: commit: xxx
8fb419aa refs/heads/another-branch@{79}: commit: xxx
```

**Can I just checkout to** `8369312d` **which is previous to that** `reset: moving to c398477fa2b2e0e78cb628c75df81b2c1ec411cd`?

Comment: When you use `-n` you tell `git cherry-pick` *not* to do its own commit(s). When you then `git cherry-pick --abort` you tell Git to put everything back to the way it was before you started. Anything you *explicitly* committed is saved and safe for a while (at least 30 days by default); things you did not commit may be difficult to impossible to recover. It may help to show a bit more of your command-line history, though. In particular I suspect you may have run `git cherry-pick -x <commit-range>` earlier.

Comment: @torek updated the question with more reflogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (but can't prove with the above text) that you must have kicked off the initial cherry-picking operation with more than one commit, e.g., using something like:

```
git cherry-pick -x 1234567..fedcba9   # possibly with -n too
```

This would have triggered Git's "sequencer".  If some individual pick operation failed, that would leave the remaining picks to do, and exit out of the command entirely.  This would then cause the later `git cherry-pick --abort` to put things back to the saved `ORIG_HEAD`, making the 70-some-odd commits you made in between seem to vanish.

> Can I just checkout to `8369312d` which is previous to that `reset: moving to c398477fa2b2e0e78cb628c75df81b2c1ec411cd`?

I believe so.  Note that this will give you a "detached HEAD", which is fine.  If `git log` then shows what you want, a subsequent `git checkout -b <newbranch>` will create a new branch name you can use to work with the commits.